# Different "store view" don't show the same product for a categories

Tags: magento-1.8

my web has 3 store views (they are used for the languages only). The configuration for each store views is global by default, and  categories y products attributes too.
The problem is there are some categories show a products list in store view default, but when it changes another language, the list load less products (in some cases 100 or 200 products).
I have check the visibility and status of products, categories, so on. I have reindexed all, and flushed cache, opened and saved categories and products...
I thought the store view did not affect that.
What could be happend?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The sql query to get collection from category uses table catalog_category_product_index that contains only  products with store id=1 (maybe becose the module to upload products).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Follow this steps and you are going to be fine

- Go to System>>Index Management
- Set action to Reindex all and submit
- Go to System>>Cache Management
- Set Action to Refresh all and submit

Cheers